# Scroll animation buildup bug

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

he everyone i was looking into this plugin by Zach Dunn found here https://github.com/buildinternet/totem
 im having trouble with the ugly animation buildup when you click on the next and previous links, i tried the `.stop()` and the `queue:false` method, or maybe im not doing right,
for some reason the code tag is funky right so so could you take a look at [GITHUB](https://github.com/buildinternet/totem)?

Apparently the author is not offering support for a while now, and im sure we could all use this fix.

Comment: Checked out the demo at http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/totem/index.html, unable to duplicate a "ugly animation buildup".

Comment: What's your current configuration?

Comment: keep clicking next or previous really fast you will se what i mean

Comment: im using the demo config

Comment: and got the same thing in all browsers i have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go.  I modified the totem script to have a blocker to keep things from registering while animating.

http://jsfiddle.net/amjCU/18/

Remove # from the `href="#"`

Comment: anything above 200 is giving me that buildup

Comment: I don't think I know what you mean by buildup.  Can you post a JSFiddle?  I'll fix it then.

Comment: here it is, [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Clazzid/amjCU/13/) if you click fast more that 5 or 6 times on the next and previous u can start to see what i mean.

Comment: i know there has to be a way to block click functions until current animation is finished, that would fix it. thanks CCCason

Comment: ok here is what i got now [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Clazzid/amjCU/15) as you can see, the next is fixed there, previous is not, the problem is that on my page whenever click is unbound (animation running) a click sends you to top. maybe change the links to clickable divs? im sure there is another way –

Comment: lol i fixed it before i saw you post, thanks a lot! i had to refmove the `href=""` completley or else it would still go to top, could you tell me which is better or more optimized? the one you posted or mine... [FIDDLE 19](http://jsfiddle.net/Clazzid/amjCU/19/)

Comment: Well, you are unbinding and rebinding which is a lot more expensive than a bool check.  So mine would be more efficient.  Plus.  If you have it stopped, yours will start it again.

Answer (score 0):

OK well i think i can live with what i got. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Clazzid/amjCU/15/)
all i did after that was remove the href from links, and changed their text to image, so the text wasn't selected on a double click. it all validates so i guess its ok.
Now i can change the speed to whatever i need, and click on the next as fast as i want! 
sorry i posted something i could answer myself, but i kinda figured out what i needed on the way.

Thanks Everyone!

Comment: yes apparently i still didnt have it there :P  CCCason got it just the way i needed! thanks a lot!